# Sql pivot - but dont sum the values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table schema that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Discounts](
      [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
      [ProductId] [varchar(50)] NOT NULL,
      [LowerBoundDays] [int] NOT NULL,
      [UpperBoundDays] [int] NOT NULL,
      [Discount] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
```

And some data like this

```
        lower       upper discount(%)
product1  0         10          0
product1  10        30          1
product1  30        60          2
product1  60        90          3
product1  90        120         4
product2  0         10          0
product2  10        30          1
product2  30        60          2
product2  60        90          3
product2  90        120         4
```

How can I do a pivot query to get 2 rows that look like this:

```
            0-10    10-30   30-60   60-90   90-120
product1    0       1       2       3       4
product2    0       1       2       3       4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, there are several ways that you can convert the rows of data into columns.

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select productid,
  max(case when lower = 0 and upper = 10 then discount end) [0-10],
  max(case when lower = 10 and upper = 30 then discount end) [10-30],
  max(case when lower = 30 and upper = 60 then discount end) [30-60],
  max(case when lower = 60 and upper = 90 then discount end) [60-90],
  max(case when lower = 90 and upper = 120 then discount end) [90-120]
from CorporateSpread
group by productid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/406cc/3).

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select productid, [0-10], [10-30], [30-60], [60-90],[90-120]
from 
(
  select productid,
    discount,
    cast(lower as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(upper as varchar(10)) rng
  from CorporateSpread
) d
pivot
(
  max(discount)
  for rng in ([0-10], [10-30], [30-60], [60-90],[90-120])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/406cc/5).

The above two version work great if you have a known number of values, but if you have an unknown number of ranges, then you will need to to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(lower as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(upper as varchar(10))) 
                    from CorporateSpread
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT productid, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select productid,
                  discount,
                  cast(lower as varchar(10)) + ''-'' + cast(upper as varchar(10)) rng
                from CorporateSpread
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(discount)
                for rng in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/406cc/7). All versions will give a result:

```
| PRODUCTID | 0-10 | 10-30 | 30-60 | 60-90 | 90-120 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|  product1 |    0 |     1 |     2 |     3 |      4 |
|  product2 |    0 |     1 |     2 |     3 |      4 |
```

Comment: doesnt this mean your query has to have knowledge of the data. As in you have had to hard code the day ranges into the case expression. what if there are different date ranges for different products. Is there a way to be more dynamic?

Comment: @ChrisCa See my edit, I added two versions using the PIVOT function, one version is using dynamic SQL